# Basic histogram filter localize a robot position

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference

We are in a 8 m corridor. Each bin is 1m wide.
There are 5 bins that are dark and three bins that are light.
The robot has a light sensor and can detect whether a certain bin is dark or light.
If the bin is dark, the sensor reports "dark" in 80% of the times and "light" in the remaining 20%.
If the bin is lighted, the sensor reports "lighted" in 95% of the times and "dark" in the remaining 5%. We start with complete ignorance.
The robot is standing still in front of a bin.
what is the probability the robot is located in front of a lighted bin given the sensor sensed 3 independent times "lighted".

The basic approach to solve the problem is to use bayes inference:
Let L be the event that the bin is lighted.
Let D be the event that the bin is dark.
Let S be the event that the sensor reports "lighted" 3 times.
P(L | S) = (P(S | L) * P(L)) / P(S)

P(S) is the probability that the sensor reports "lighted" 3 times in a row. Since the sensor's measurements are independent. Can we multiply the individual probabilities together?
Or should I use an iterative approach where the prior is updated each time the sensor reports "lighted"? How to reason about the correct approach? The results are different.